# How to set relationships between wordpress custom post types

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following custom post types set up in my wordpresss installation:
Clients and Testimonials.

In Testimonials custom post types I have these fields (simplified):

- Testimonial quote
- Client name

In Clients custom post type I have these fields (simplified):

- Client name
- Client description

Question: Currently the "Client name" field in the "Testimonials post type is a text box but would like this to be a drop down list based on the entries in the "Clients" post type.

Ideally, I would like to do this without a plug-in if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using get_posts in select box like as follows

```
<select>
<?php 
$all_client = get_posts(array('post_type'=> 'Client-post-type','posts_per_page'   => -1) ); 
foreach($all_client as $single_client){
echo "<option value='".$single_client->ID."'>'".$single_client->post_title."'</option>";
}?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, how to add a select box in the edit area for the testimonials post?

Comment: You need to add separate metabox for this post type. you can see more here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box